# Ruby on Rails - Localhost and Heroku queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm using rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3.

I am having issues deploying to heroku. The functionality I'm trying to achieve is working, but only locally, and I am using Postgres locally as well.

The query is (I got more of these queries, but the symptoms are the same):

```
pesquisa=pesquisa.joins('INNER JOIN facilities_hotels ON hotels.id=facilities_hotels.hotel_id')
         pesquisa=pesquisa.where('facilities_hotels.facility_id in (:fc_list)', :fc_list => params[:fc]).uniq
         pesquisa=pesquisa.group('hotels.id','hotel.name',<other fields>').having('count(facility_id) = :tamanho', :tamanho => params[:fc].size)
```

Locally this is returning all the right stuff, but on Heroku, it returns no data at all.

Comment: Is there data on heroku?

Comment: Yes, there is data there. And all code is the same. I believe the syntax is correct as well, but I'm opened to suggestions :)

Comment: From your console run `heroku run console` and run some commands to make sure your data is there. Like `Hotel.first`, `Facility.first`, `Facility.first.hotels` etc.

Comment: I did like you instructed and the data was all there. I can create records with HABTM no problem, the data is all there. The query is what is giving the headache :/

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is making sure you ran your migrations on Heroku.

Comment: Try running the query in the console, but drop the `having` clause

Comment: Not really a solution, but have you considered querying using ActiveRecord associations instead of custom SQL commands? It may be less error prone

Comment: Well I am using association, it is not pure SQL, neither it is AREL. I'm a RoR beginner and was told that when I had several conditions on where to use or not use AR to solve this, and since I have many conditions and querys with several inner joins, this way seemed more "clear".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the data being different.

Among all the pushes and pulls from the git repo, somehow the IDs of the join table in the HABTM associations were different from their primary tables.